# UITableView Hangs with Large Data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a scenario that I am retrieving an HTML string from a database and loading that HTML file into a Cell using `UITextView`. An issue I am facing is that the `TableView` hangs for a chunk of time that reduces the performance of the application. and with huge data this issue becomes horrible and sometimes the application crashes! I am looking for a solution which can make my app's `Tableview` scrolling smoother and fast.

I am using custom cell here.

I have tried with many ways but still can't reach my goal. Need some expert advice!

Comment: are you reusing cells? some code might help.

Comment: Are all HTML strings too big, or just a few? If just a few, perhaps you can replace the HTML with something simpler (i.e, text 'too big to show')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use blocks? Try to use this dispatch function where ever your doing the download of the HTML string:

```
dispatch_queue_t download = dispatch_queue_create("downloadQueue", nil);
            dispatch_async(download, ^{
                // Write download code that stalls UI here.
            });
```

Please note, do not place any UIKit code inside of the block since it is only allowed to run on the main thread, this will cause your application to crash.To work around this you need to add:

```
dispatch_queue_t download = dispatch_queue_create("downloadQueue", nil);
            dispatch_async(download, ^{
                // Write download code that stalls UI here.

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //Write UIKit code here, example:
                    [tableView reloadData];
                });
            });
```